# View doesn't respond to touches after shake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

In my app I've implemented a shake event and it shows a UIImageView. When the UIImageView is shown, I hide the Nav Bar with:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

And after that I want to bring it back when user touches the screen:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}
```

But it doesn't work! Like my view doesn't respond to touches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like it was shaken a little to hard...

Comment: Well, I hope I haven't broken the iPad simulator :)

Answer (score 1):

You many need to enable user interaction on your view if it isn't already.

Comment: It is enabled. Actually, it's enabled in IB by default.

Comment: Are you trying to receive touches on the UIImageView?